# How to accept integer only and ignore other data types?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in C++ and I'm wondering if you can help me.

I'm making a program and error checking is required for this program.
So, how can I accept integer only and ignore other data type?

For example:

```
int tilenumber;
cin >> tilenumber;
cin.clear();
cin.ignore();
cin >> words;
```

When my code runs:

Input :  1
         hey i wanna dance

Output : ey i wanna dance

///

What I want:

Case 1:
Input : 1

hey i wanna dance

Output : hey i wanna dance

Case 2:
Input : 1e

hey i wanna dance

Output : hey i wanna dance

Why does my code not working?

I tried to solve my problem with my code like above but it's not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Read all data as strings.   Then check the content of the strings to extract integral values, and discard anything else you don't need.    C++ I/O functions won't do that sort of checking for you - if you need it, you have to read the input and check it yourself.

Comment: thank you! @Peter I'll give it a try

Comment: `cin >> tilenumber` sets `cin`'s `failbit` state if the conversion fails.  Always check the stream's state after extracting input, eg: `if (cin >> tilenumber) { use tilenumber ... } else { error ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Read the entire string and utilize the [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    std::string tempstr;
    std::getline(std::cin, tempstr);
    try {
        int result = std::stoi(tempstr);
        std::cout << "The result is: " << result;
    }
    catch (std::invalid_argument) {
        std::cout << "Could not convert to integer.";
    }
}
```

Alternative is to utilize the [std::stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and do the parsing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    std::string tempstr;
    std::getline(std::cin, tempstr);
    std::stringstream ss(tempstr);
    int result;
    if (ss >> result) {
        std::cout << "The result is: " << result;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Could not convert to integer.";
    }
}
```